# How to get the date of every upcoming Friday in mm.dd.yy format in Google App Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I would like to retrieve the date in format `mm.dd.yy` for every upcoming friday. Let's say today is Wednesday, the 9th of September. The next upcoming Friday would be September, 11th or 09/11/2020. How do I program this logic using JavaScript?

```
var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "mm.dd.yy")
var next_friday = ?
```

Any pointers would help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with JS without any libraries.

First, figure out what 'day' the current date represents. `new Date().getDay()` will return you a value between 0(sun) - 6(sat). Now that you know what day of the week it is, you can simply do a little math to figure out when the next closest friday is.

```
const now = new Date();
// The next friday is this many days away. Actually this is a current/next
// thursday and we are adding a day so we can simplify the expression.
const offset =  ((11 - date.getDay()) % 7) + 1;

now.setDate(now.getDate() + offset); // add days to friday to our time.
```

So all together you can wrap that into a function and stick it in a helpers file somewhere. You can even parameterize the day, so you can find arbitrary days.

```
const today = new Date("09/13/2020");

const nextDay = (date, day) => {
  const result = new Date(date.getTime());
  const offset = (((day + 6) - date.getDay()) % 7) + 1;
  
  result.setDate(date.getDate() + offset);

  return result;
};

const days = {
  sunday: 0,
  monday: 1,
  tuesday: 2,
  wednesday: 3,
  thursday: 4,
  friday: 5,
  saturday: 6
};

const nextFriday = (date) => nextDay(date, days.friday);

console.log(nextFriday(today)); // hopefully 9/18/2020
```

Formatting would just be finding each component from the result date and concatenating them together.

```
const today = new Date("09/13/2020");

const formatDate = (date) => {
  const month = `${date.getMonth() + 1}`.padStart(2, "00");
  const day = `${date.getDate()}`.padStart(2, "00");
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  
  return `${month}.${day}.${year}`;
}

console.log(formatDate(today));
```

Comment: This `(12 - date.getDay()) % 7` can be simplified to `((11 - date.getDay()) % 7)+1`

Comment: Absolutely! Completely missed that, good catch. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using https://github.com/datejs/Datejs

```js
console.log(Date.next().friday())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datejs/1.0/date.min.js"></script>
```

```js
var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date.next().friday(), "GMT+1", "mm.dd.yy")
var next_friday = Utilities.formatDate(Date.next().friday(), "GMT+1", "mm.dd.yy")
```

Comment: Did you include the date.js library?

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/L0pdhtmr/1/